# FILTER_VALIDATE_INT validates URL encoded values as INT

Tags: php, security, filtering, sanitization, filter-var

Why does the `query`: `*.php?page=%20%209999%20%20` and id est `*.php?page=%0a%0d9999%0a%0d` validate as `INT` and return as `int(9999)`?

```
$args=array('page'=>array('filter'=>FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)));
$ret=filter_input_array(INPUT_GET,$args);

var_dump($ret['page']);
```

Comment: Those "URL encoded values" are just spaces `%20` and linebreaks `%0A`.

Comment: @mario Right, but since when are spaces and linebreaks integers?

Comment: `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT` is not much different to `intval()`. It doesn't assert strings to be all-numeric, it just probes for integernishness.

Comment: @mario I see. Bit vague on the devpage I suppose. =(

Comment: Yeah, the filter module is a nice idea with a somewhat clumsy API and documentation that deviates from a few implementation details :]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encoded URL is:

```
*.php?page=%20%209999%20%20
```

The decoded URL is:

```
*.php?page=  9999
```

hence you observe `int(9999)`. `%20` and `%0A` are spaces and linebreaks, respectively. This behavior can be observed with the following code:

```
$_GET["page"] = "  9999  ";
$name = filter_var($_GET["page"], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
var_dump($name);
```

> int(9999)

Those URL-encoded spaces and breaks are being urldecoded before they get to your filter, and `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT` is not so strict with whitespace.

One way to adjust your filter is to use a [callback](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.misc.php) to be more strict with integer testing:

```
$_GET["page"] = "  9999   ";

function FILTER_VALIDATE_STRICT_INT($val) {
    return intval(urlencode($val)) === intval($val) ? intval($val) : false;
}

$args=array(
    'page'=>array(
        'filter'=>FILTER_CALLBACK,
        'options'=>"FILTER_VALIDATE_STRICT_INT"));
$ret=filter_var_array($_GET, $args);

var_dump($ret['page']);
```

Returns

> bool(false)

Comment: this is more an observation, wouldn't you agree? Mario already stated that in comments.

Comment: "Why does the query: ... validate as INT and return as int(9999)" - that was the question.

Comment: well, then again.. the OP did ask *Why does...* so... they never asked how to fix it lol yeah.. you're right ;-)

Comment: I'll try to help him out...

Comment: @Drakes Right, but since when is a space / linebreak an integer?

Comment: `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT` might not be as strict as we presume it is. I've included a solution for you in my answer because this was a fun question.